# illustrator cs6 Gujarati Font Issue Shruti font?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I am using Illustrator CS6.

Recently when I try to type in our local language "Gujarati" via Google Input tools with Gujarati fonts the typed text not showing joined word and characters correctly.

[image]

This is how it looks in illustrator cs6
enter image description here

It is working correctly everywhere except Photoshop. This is how is should look (typed in Chrome):

[image]

To better understand my problem, there is a similar question on Stack Overflow. That problem is for Android and my question is for Illustrator CS6.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator CC includes enhanced support for Indic languages. You can now create documents using Indic text. The additional Middle Eastern & South Asian Composer provides correct word shaping for many of the non-Western scripts.

The Middle Eastern & South Asian Composers support Indian languages:

Bengali
Gujarati
Hindi
Kannada
Malayalam
Marathi
Oriya
Punjabi
Tamil
Telugu
This feature is enabled through the Preferences menu **(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>). The option is available in Preferences > Type > Show Indic Options.**

[image]

Setting to switch on Indic options, in the Preferences

When you enable Indic options, two additional composers are enabled in the flyout menu of the Paragraph panel **(available in the Control panel or through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)**. The two additional options are:

- **Middle Eastern & South Asian Single-line Composer**
- **Middle Eastern & South Asian Every-line Composer**

[image]

Two new composers available when you switch on Indic support